# javascript mappings not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Can anyone say why in typescript/angular this doesn't work:

```
this.errorMessage = Object.keys(c.errors).map((key) => this.myArray[this.currentKey]).join(' ');
```

but this does:

```
this.errorMessage = Object.keys(c.errors).map((key) => this.myArray[this.currentKey as 'x']).join(' ');
```

even though I made sure that this.currentKey = Object.keys(c.errors)[0]; is evaluated to 'x'

By the way, the two objects I interact with are initialised previously as follows:

```
errorMessage = '';
myArray= {
    x: 'Message 1',
    y: 'Message 2'
  };
```

and c.errors returns in one case

> x: true

in another casse it could be

> y: true

Comment: Its not true that arrow functions "doesnt not have" this. They do have a lexical "this" coming from surroundings. Therefore you dont need to bind "this"

Comment: Probably a number of reasons. Also, you never use your `key` variable in the callback, so why are you doing all this?

Comment: @CristianS.  `Its not true that arrow functions "doesnt not have" this.`  It is true :),  Scoping rules just still apply that's all..

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this.currentKey` inside the map function while you can simply use the arg `key`. And keep in mind the scope of "this" since you are using an arrow function.